# Dúvida sobre "código criptografado" (ofuscado) em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Queria saber se este código encontra-se criptografado:

```
$(document)["\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79"](function(){$("\x23\x6A\x71\x75\x65\x72\x79\x5F\x6A\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x65\x72\x5F\x31")["\x6A\x50\x6C\x61\x79\x65\x72"]({ready:function(event){$(this)["\x6A\x50\x6C\x61\x79\x65\x72"]("\x73\x65\x74\x4D\x65\x64\x69\x61",{oga:"\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x36\x34\x2E\x33\x31\x2E\x33\x30\x2E\x39\x31\x3A\x39\x38\x39\x36\x2F\x3B\x73\x74\x72\x65\x61\x6D\x2F\x31"})},swfPath:"\x6A\x73",supplied:"\x6F\x67\x61",wmode:"\x77\x69\x6E\x64\x6F\x77",smoothPlayBar:true,keyEnabled:true})});$(function(){if( typeof playlist==="\x75\x6E\x64\x65\x66\x69\x6E\x65\x64"){playlist=[{artist:"\x6F\x75\x72\x6F",title:"\x54\x65\x63\x68\x6E\x6F\x6C\x6F\x67\x69\x63",mp3:"\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x36\x34\x2E\x33\x31\x2E\x33\x30\x2E\x39\x31\x3A\x39\x38\x39\x36\x2F\x3B\x73\x74\x72\x65\x61\x6D\x2F\x31"},{artist:"\x44\x61\x66\x74\x20\x50\x75\x6E\x6B",title:"\x48\x75\x6D\x61\x6E\x20\x41\x66\x74\x65\x72\x20\x41\x6C\x6C",mp3:"\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x63\x6F\x6E\x65\x63\x74\x72\x61\x64\x69\x6F\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2E\x62\x72\x2F\x70\x6C\x61\x79"}]};var currentTrack=0;var numTracks=playlist["\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68"];$("\x2E\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x65\x72\x2D\x6E\x65\x78\x74")["\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B"](function(){player["\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x4E\x65\x78\x74"]()});$("\x2E\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x65\x72\x2D\x70\x72\x65\x76")["\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B"](function(){player["\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x50\x72\x65\x76\x69\x6F\x75\x73"]()});player=$("\x2E\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x65\x72")["\x6A\x50\x6C\x61\x79\x65\x72"]({ready:function(){player["\x6A\x50\x6C\x61\x79\x65\x72"]("\x73\x65\x74\x4D\x65\x64\x69\x61",playlist[currentTrack]);player["\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x43\x75\x72\x72\x65\x6E\x74"]();},ended:function(){$(this)["\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x4E\x65\x78\x74"]()},play:function(){$("\x2E\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x65\x72\x2D\x63\x75\x72\x72\x65\x6E\x74\x2D\x74\x72\x61\x63\x6B")["\x74\x65\x78\x74"](playlist[currentTrack]["\x61\x72\x74\x69\x73\x74"]+"\x20\x2D\x20"+playlist[currentTrack]["\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65"])},swfPath:"\x6A\x73\x2F\x70\x6C\x75\x67\x69\x6E\x73\x2F\x6A\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x65\x72\x2F",supplied:"\x6D\x70\x33",cssSelectorAncestor:"",cssSelector:{play:"\x23\x62\x74\x5F\x70\x6C\x61\x79",pause:"\x23\x62\x74\x5F\x70\x61\x75\x73\x65",stop:"\x23\x62\x74\x5F\x70\x61\x75\x73\x65",seekBar:"\x2E\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x65\x72\x2D\x74\x69\x6D\x65\x6C\x69\x6E\x65",playBar:"\x2E\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x65\x72\x2D\x74\x69\x6D\x65\x6C\x69\x6E\x65\x2D\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x72\x6F\x6C"},size:{width:"\x31\x70\x78",height:"\x31\x70\x78"}});player["\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x4E\x65\x78\x74"]=function(){currentTrack=(currentTrack==(numTracks-1))?0:++currentTrack;player["\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x43\x75\x72\x72\x65\x6E\x74"]();};player["\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x50\x72\x65\x76\x69\x6F\x75\x73"]=function(){currentTrack=(currentTrack==0)?numTracks-1:--currentTrack;player["\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x43\x75\x72\x72\x65\x6E\x74"]();};player["\x70\x6C\x61\x79\x43\x75\x72\x72\x65\x6E\x74"]=function(){player["\x6A\x50\x6C\x61\x79\x65\x72"]("\x73\x65\x74\x4D\x65\x64\x69\x61",playlist[currentTrack])["\x6A\x50\x6C\x61\x79\x65\x72"]("\x70\x6C\x61\x79")};});
```

Se sim, há como eu descriptografá-lo?

Comment: Criptografado esta, mas é estralho usar Hexadecimal pra isso, segue [esta tabela](http://187.7.106.14/marcelo/org_comp/tabelaASCII.pdf) que da pra descriptografar.

Comment: Se não for pedir muito, otimize o código, com [esta ferramenta](http://jsbeautifier.org/), é terrível ler código extenso assim.

Answer (score 14):

O código não está criptografado, apenas parcialmente ofuscado. Quem fez isso se aproveitou do fato de que strings em JavaScript podem conter qualquer caractere UTF-16 escapado no formato `\xNN`, onde `NN` é o código hexadecimal do caractere.

Se você criptografar de verdade um código JS, ele não será mais utilizável, pois os browsers não conseguiriam interpretá-lo. Portanto a única solução para tentar dificultar que o código seja indevidamente apropriado é ofuscá-lo, o que não adianta muito pois é facilmente reversível.

Comment: Pior que nesse caso a pessoa ainda conseguiu ocupar um absurdo a mais de espaço do que o código original.

Answer (score 4):

Ele é um tipo de `obfuscator`, pode ser feito através de serviço online também como este: https://javascriptobfuscator.com/

Já vi alguns que funcionam através do npm, por exemplo, mas nunca consegui o mesmo resultado deste online. Nunca me aprofundei muito também no assunto, mas sempre usei esse online que sempre serviu bem, sempre rodou corretamente online e tudo mais.

Mas repito, nunca me aprofundei muito no assunto e, até onde eu sei, nunca encontrei uma ferramenta que pudesse reverter esse `obfuscator`.

#### Edit:

Note que esse tipo de criptografia é diferente de um 'uglify' que vai apenas, a grosso modo, "renomear" suas funções.

#### Edit2:

Baseado nas outras respostas, já vi que não funciona do modo como havia aprendido.

Comment: Ajudou Thanks!!!

Comment: Ofuscador pra valer é esse daqui: http://www.jsfuck.com/

Answer (score 2):

Está em Hexadecimal. Eu me perguntou porque que fazem isso.

http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.htm

Esse site acima descriptografa. Pelo que vi são os nomes dos elementos criptografados.

Ficando assim:

```
$(document)["ready"](function() {
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1")["jPlayer"]({
        ready: function(event) {
            $(this)["jPlayer"]("setMedia", {
                oga: "http://64.31.30.91:9896/;stream/1"
            })
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "oga",
        wmode: "window",
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true
    })
});
$(function() {
    if (typeof playlist === "undefined") {
        playlist = [{
            artist: "ouro",
            title: "Technologic",
            mp3: "http://64.31.30.91:9896/;stream/1"
        }, {
            artist: "Daft Punk",
            title: "Human After All",
            mp3: "http://conectradio.com.br/play"
        }]
    };
    var currentTrack = 0;
    var numTracks = playlist["length"];
    $(".player-next")["click"](function() {
        player["playNext"]()
    });
    $(".player-prev")["click"](function() {
        player["playPrevious"]()
    });
    player = $(".player")["jPlayer"]({
        ready: function() {
            player["jPlayer"]("setMedia", playlist[currentTrack]);
            player["playCurrent"]();
        },
        ended: function() {
            $(this)["playNext"]()
        },
        play: function() {
            $(".player-current-track")["text"](playlist[currentTrack]["artist"] + " - " + playlist[currentTrack]["title"])
        },
        swfPath: "js/plugins/jplayer/",
        supplied: "mp3",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "",
        cssSelector: {
            play: "#bt_play",
            pause: "#bt_pause",
            stop: "#bt_pause",
            seekBar: ".player-timeline",
            playBar: ".player-timeline-control"
        },
        size: {
            width: "1px",
            height: "1px"
        }
    });
    player["playNext"] = function() {
        currentTrack = (currentTrack == (numTracks - 1)) ? 0 : ++currentTrack;
        player["playCurrent"]();
    };
    player["playPrevious"] = function() {
        currentTrack = (currentTrack == 0) ? numTracks - 1 : --currentTrack;
        player["playCurrent"]();
    };
    player["playCurrent"] = function() {
        player["jPlayer"]("setMedia", playlist[currentTrack])["jPlayer"]("play")
    };
});
```

Comment: Mas então, você teria alguma orientação sobre criptografia de código JS?

Comment: JS por definição é público. Frescura.

Comment: Ajudou Muito Thanks!!!

Comment: @TaoPaiPai mas por que frescura? Digamos que eu tenha um código JS que execute diversas funções em meu site, mas não quero que ninguém pegue ele, ou coisas do tipo. Uma tentativa de 'proteger' não seria viável? Sei que isso é bem dizer impossível, pois o JS precisa ser lido em client.

Comment: Você mesmo já respondeu. E tem vários outros motivos. O @bfavaretto falou um deles.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade, no máximo você pode proteger os seus scripts no servidor, por exemplo armazenando os mesmos dentro de uma DLL ou através de um link dinâmico (por exemplo, o script aponta para `http://localhost/script?uuid=f3f475de-f252-4d25-a3ee-1d1bba72f113`, então a sua pagina script vai descriptografar o script e devolver para o Browser) , mesmo com todo este trabalho, o script estará disponível no cliente, por alguem com acesso ao servidor não conseguirá copiar todos os seus scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Olá.
Nunca tinha visto codificação em javascript, então talvez esteja errado, porém pesquisando rapidamente encontrei uma possível solução.

O resultado do código postado por você e decodificado foi:

```
$(document)["ready"](function(){$("#jquery_jplayer_1")["jPlayer"]({ready:function(event){$(this)["jPlayer"]("setMedia",{oga:"http://64.31.30.91:9896/;stream/1"})},swfPath:"js",supplied:"oga",wmode:"window",smoothPlayBar:true,keyEnabled:true})});$(function(){if( typeof playlist==="undefined"){playlist=[{artist:"ouro",title:"Technologic",mp3:"http://64.31.30.91:9896/;stream/1"},{artist:"Daft Punk",title:"Human After All",mp3:"http://conectradio.com.br/play"}]};var currentTrack=0;var numTracks=playlist["length"];$(".player-next")["click"](function(){player["playNext"]()});$(".player-prev")["click"](function(){player["playPrevious"]()});player=$(".player")["jPlayer"]({ready:function(){player["jPlayer"]("setMedia",playlist[currentTrack]);player["playCurrent"]();},ended:function(){$(this)["playNext"]()},play:function(){$(".player-current-track")["text"](playlist[currentTrack]["artist"]+" - "+playlist[currentTrack]["title"])},swfPath:"js/plugins/jplayer/",supplied:"mp3",cssSelectorAncestor:"",cssSelector:{play:"#bt_play",pause:"#bt_pause",stop:"#bt_pause",seekBar:".player-timeline",playBar:".player-timeline-control"},size:{width:"1px",height:"1px"}});player["playNext"]=function(){currentTrack=(currentTrack==(numTracks-1))?0:++currentTrack;player["playCurrent"]();};player["playPrevious"]=function(){currentTrack=(currentTrack==0)?numTracks-1:--currentTrack;player["playCurrent"]();};player["playCurrent"]=function(){player["jPlayer"]("setMedia",playlist[currentTrack])["jPlayer"]("play")};});
```

fonte: http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/

Se for a solução, por favor, sinalize-a.

Comment: Ajudou muito Thanks!!!